How to get bold text for symbols in a heading
One thing I have never been able to fix it the headings which don't print the symbols of latex like they print the text. For instance:
\documentclass[bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{nccmath,        % for \mfrac: medium size of \frac
            mathtools}      % it load amsmath tools
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} % for writing absolute values
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\usepackage{esint}          % new, for integrals
\usepackage{derivative}     % new, for commands for writing derivatives in a straightforward manner
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Ss}{\mathbb{S}}
\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\newcommand{\on}{\operatorname}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}

\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.95}
\DeclareTCBListing{mintedbox}{O{}m!O{}}{%
  breakable=true,
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  minted language=#2,
  minted style=default,
  minted options={%
    linenos,
    gobble=0,
    breaklines=true,
    breakafter=,,
    fontsize=\small,
    numbersep=8pt,
    #1},
  boxsep=0pt,
  left skip=0pt,
  right skip=0pt,
  left=25pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=3pt,
  bottom=3pt,
  arc=5pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=2pt,
  toprule=2pt,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=orange!70,
  enhanced,
  overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \fill[orange!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=20pt]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}},
  #3}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}           % should be last in reamble

\begin{document}
\author{\begin{large} Hand-in exercises set 1
\end{large}\\Author}
\title{Differential Geometry}

\maketitle

\subsection{Show that $\phi_1$ defines local coordinates on $U_1$.}
\begin{definition}
    A chart is a mapping from a region of a manifold \textit{M} to Euclidean space $\R^n$ 
\end{definition}

\end{document}

shows

with phi and U_1 in standard non-bold.
How can I get this in bold?
Thanks

We can't compile your code fragment if \end{document} is missing

→ How to make mathematics bold in headings

As you didn't provide enough details, my suggestion is my guess only, try with
\subsection{\mathversion{bold}Show that $\phi_1$ defines local coordinates on $U_1$.}

Please use \usepackage{amsmath} for the tag \mathversion

Be careful: This would add \mathversion{bold} also to the table of contents and running head.

It worked, but I get "Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `math shift' on input line 157."

@Superunknown As I already mentioned in my comment under your question, please provide the complete MWE

Thanks, but what is MWE?

@Superunknown Please refer https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Ok, I added the preamble

Please check @samcarter; comment and fix the same
